# talib.EMA() returning nan values

Tags: python, numpy, ta-lib

So I have the following code :

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import bt

import numpy as np

import talib

btc_data = pd.read_csv('Binance_BTCUSDT_minute.csv', index_col= 'date', parse_dates = True)

one = btc_data['close'] #one minute candles

**closes = np.array(one)**  #numpy array of one minute candles

five = one.resample('5min').mean() #five minute candles

type(one),type(five),type(one[0]),type(five[0]) #comparing types
(they are the exact same type)


period_short = 55

period_long = 144

**closes = np.array(five)** #I can comment this out if I want to use one minute candles instead

EMA_short = talib.EMA(closes, timeperiod= period_short)

EMA_long = talib.EMA(closes, timeperiod= period_long)
```

The weird part is that when I use the one minute candles, the EMAs return numerical values. But when I use five minute candles, it returns nan

I compared the types of both, and they are the same type (both the arrays and the values contained are numpy.ndarray and numpy.float64 respectively). Why is the 5 minute then unable to produce values ?

Comment: If I recall right rolling EMA of period N can't be calculated for first N-1 values. Python wrapper of talib returns NaNs for these values. Then real results are appended. If your data is shorter than timeperiod - all results will be NaNs.

Comment: My data has more than enough history to be able to create a 5min chart. The inputted file is a csv file containing historical btc price data from September 2020... It should be able to generate my desired EMAs.

Comment: And your `five` is not full of no NaNs at `five = one.resample('5min').mean() `?

Comment: nope. I double checked that too and they were formatted in the same way

Comment: Can you upload a piece of the data somewhere so I could reproduce?

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I got my data from here : https://www.cryptodatadownload.com/data/binance/                                                         Just scroll down and there'll be minute by minute data.  You have to open the excel file and delete the first row for it to work. Try and let me know.

Comment: You have 189 NaNs in `five` after `one.resample('5min').mean()`. Use `(np.isnan(five)).sum(0)` to check.

Comment: awesome. got it now thanks